# Architecture - Remote Database for Mobile Blazor Bindings

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have chosen the **Blazor-Server-side** and in addition, I am using **Mobile Blazor bindings** for an **Android App**.

Now I am clueless about the best practice on where to place the **DatabaseContext for a remote Cloud Database.**

Any tips on the architecture of this?

Comment: Not so clear how that fits together. What runs where and who calls who?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've taken a look at https://github.com/Eilon/CatTrackerDemo but I am unsure of where to place the DB.